# jetty and etc environment on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, jetty, environment

When running jetty project under IntelliJ I have no problem to read environment variable I set to /etc/environment using the System.getenv("var1") api.

When I deploy the war to Ubuntu server that start Jetty at boot, I get null when calling System.getenv("var1")

When I run a simple console application on the server under my user (suder user) I get the environment variable currently.

What I need to do in order to make the environment variables in /etc/environment visible to the war when it start automatically not under a user session?

Answer (score 1):

I think I needed to adjust this in the jetty.sh when I was getting things working on elastic beanstalk...

In the jetty.sh script you can source the /etc/environment file and they will be present.  If that is what you are looking for then open a bug for it and we'll add it into the jetty.sh script for the next release.

Comment: I noticed this behaviour.  if I start Jetty with **sudo /etc/init.d/jetty8 restart** every thing work fine. But after boot or restarting Jetty with the command **sudo service jetty8 restart** its not working.  From Ubuntu documentation  "service  runs  a  System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /."  What should I do order to avoid re running Jetty after boot with a user context.  I tried to source /etc/environment by adding ". /etc/environment" on /etc/init.d/jetty8 without success.