# System environment variables in Jetty application

Tags: java, jetty, environment-variables, jetty-9

How to configure system environment variables inside one Jetty application?

e.g. For database connection details, putting it in file and checking it into cvs is bad idea. For that reason using system environment is one way to go. While the system environment variables are defined in `/etc/environments` file or `.bashrc/.zshrc` file , in Jetty application, doing `System.getenv("variable_name")` won't give anything. It will result in null.

I have read this question: [Configuring a Jetty application with env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157904/configuring-a-jetty-application-with-env-variables) which concludes that which tells that Jetty doesn't support `System.getenv()` and not even in `start.ini` file.

And [jetty and etc environment on ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884105/jetty-and-etc-environment-on-ubuntu-12-10) which says `In the jetty.sh script you can source the /etc/environment file and they will be present.` which I tried and didn't get the values as expected meaning it gave me only null.

If I can't use the default `System.getenv()` or in any `.ini` file then how to specify credentials such as Database connection etc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not supporting `System.getenv()` is not a Jetty thing, but a Java thing.

There are ton of restrictions around `System.getenv()` and your environment, making it nearly useless in all but the most naive and basic test case. (eg: multiline values are not supported. multiline entries can break parsing. keys without values are not supported. keys without values can often merge with next key during parsing. entries with non US-ASCII characters are not supported.  entries with control characters are not supported.)

The common technique when using System Environment variables with Java programs is to use the shell specific techniques to obtain the values and inject them either on the command line, or into a ini file format for Jetty to then use.

Depending on your technique, these values would either show up as Jetty properties, or as Java System Properties.

Just created a project to demonstrate 4 ways to accomplish this at

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-external-config

## External Configuration Properties with Jetty

Demonstration of how to configure simple properties that can be accessed
by Servlets within Jetty.

This demonstration shows 4 different ways to configure a property
at runtime, that can then be read by the Servlet running within
Jetty.

### The props.war

This is a simple war file with a single HttpServlet and a WEB-INF/web.xml

```
[jetty-external-config]$ jar -tvf target/props.war 
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 META-INF/
   131 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 WEB-INF/
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 WEB-INF/classes/org/
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 WEB-INF/classes/org/eclipse/
     0 Mon Feb 23 09:02:14 MST 2015 WEB-INF/classes/org/eclipse/demo/
  2188 Mon Feb 23 09:02:12 MST 2015 WEB-INF/classes/org/eclipse/demo/PropsServlet.class
   572 Mon Feb 23 08:45:22 MST 2015 WEB-INF/web.xml
```

See PropsServlet.java for details of behavior.

Just compile the top level and the war file will be built and placed in all of the demo jetty.base locations for this project.

### Example #1: Basic Command Line

The `/base-command-line` project contains a simple `start.ini` which starts jetty on port 9090, and deploys the webapp. no extra configuration is done by the on-disk configuration.

If you start it up like so ...

```
[base-command-line]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116/start.jar
2015-02-23 09:15:46.088:INFO::main: Logging initialized @290ms
2015-02-23 09:15:46.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
2015-02-23 09:15:46.235:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/joakim/code/stackoverflow/jetty-external-config/base-command-line/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-02-23 09:15:46.325:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /props, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2015-02-23 09:15:46.343:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6e7f61a3{/props,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9090-props.war-_props-any-27537844855769703.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/props.war}
2015-02-23 09:15:46.353:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@67cd35c5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2015-02-23 09:15:46.353:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @555ms
```

you'll see that it has started up and deployed to the `/props` context path.

From here you can test for properties in the servlet via tooling like `wget` or `curl`.

Example:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props

[java.runtime.name] = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
[sun.boot.library.path] = /home/joakim/java/jvm/jdk-7u75-x64/jre/lib/amd64
[java.vm.version] = 24.75-b04
[java.vm.vendor] = Oracle Corporation
[java.vendor.url] = http://java.oracle.com/
...
[file.separator] = /
[java.vendor.url.bug] = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
[sun.io.unicode.encoding] = UnicodeLittle
[sun.cpu.endian] = little
[sun.desktop] = gnome
[sun.cpu.isalist] =
```

You can even request a specific property ..

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props/user.timezone
[user.timezone] = America/Phoenix
```

Lets stop the server and run it with a system property of our choice.

Notice the `-Dfoo=bar` ?

```
[base-command-line]$ java -Dfoo=bar -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116/start.jar
2015-02-23 09:15:46.088:INFO::main: Logging initialized @290ms
2015-02-23 09:15:46.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
2015-02-23 09:15:46.235:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/joakim/code/stackoverflow/jetty-external-config/base-command-line/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-02-23 09:15:46.325:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /props, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2015-02-23 09:15:46.343:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6e7f61a3{/props,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9090-props.war-_props-any-27537844855769703.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/props.war}
2015-02-23 09:15:46.353:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@67cd35c5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2015-02-23 09:15:46.353:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @555ms
```

and look for it via curl ...

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props/foo
[foo] = bar
```

That demonstrates access of a property that was specified via the command line, now lets look at the other choices.

### Example #2: Using start.ini

The `/base-startini` project contains a simple `start.ini` which starts jetty on port 9090, and deploys the webapp.

This `start.ini` also contains a `foo.ish` property.

Lets start up Jetty and try our props servlet access again ...

```
[base-startini]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116/start.jar
2015-02-23 09:16:46.088:INFO::main: Logging initialized @290ms
2015-02-23 09:16:46.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
```

and request it via curl ...

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props/foo.ish
[foo.ish] = bar
```

### Example #3: Using start.d optional ini

The `/base-startd` project contains a simple `start.ini` which starts jetty on port 9090, and deploys the webapp.

This `start.ini` also contains no extra properties that we are interested in.

The `start.d/myconf.ini` contains a property called `foo.d` that we are interested in.

Lets start up Jetty and try our props servlet access again ...

```
[base-startd]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116/start.jar
2015-02-23 09:19:46.088:INFO::main: Logging initialized @290ms
2015-02-23 09:19:46.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
```

and request it via curl ...

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props/foo.d
[foo.d] = over here
```

### Example #4: Using --include-jetty-dir optional config

The `/base-jettyinclude` project contains a new `start.ini` which starts jetty on port 9090, and deploys the webapp.

This `start.ini` also contains no extra properties that we are interested in.

However, the `start.ini` uses the `--include-jetty-dir=../jettydir` optional configuration that points to an entirely new interrim jetty.base configuration source.

The `../jettydir/start.ini` contains a property called `foo.jetty.dir` that we are interested in.

Lets start up Jetty and try our props servlet access again ...

```
[base-jettyinclude]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116/start.jar
2015-02-23 09:24:46.088:INFO::main: Logging initialized @290ms
2015-02-23 09:24:46.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
```

and request it via curl ...

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/props/props/foo.jetty.dir
[foo.jetty.dir] = more of the same
```

Comment: In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157904/configuring-a-jetty-application-with-env-variables#27158531 `System.getProperties().contains("dbhost")` - but neither adding `dbhost="localhost"` nor `-Ddbhost="localhost"` to the `start.ini` file works`  So providing them to start.ini file also doesn't help as I have tried that from that comment. Can you edit your answer and include a small script on how to do what you suggested ?

Comment: "Not supporting System.getenv() is not a Jetty thing, but a Java thing", I have looked in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String) and see no evidence that it is a "Java thing" that environment variables are not supported? Or do I misunderstand? If they're a good idea or not is not the same as if they're supported. It does seem to be a Jetty-specific thing that they're not supported.

Comment: getenv() has been [removed, then added](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4199068), then removed again, then added again.  Its got a long history of issues, and is still not stable, even today.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Awesome post. Thank you for the detail guide and example.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have the following use case. 3rd party server (I do not control the code) packaged as WAR, which consumes AWS STS regional endpoint using System.getenv https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-sts-regionalized-endpoints.html. I need to pass AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS environment variable to the process running the server. Is this not supported by Jetty as of 2022 ? It is what is keeping me with Tomcat. Is Jetty open to PR to support this use case ?